# For an epidemic model, I got a negative 'basic reproduction number' obtained by next-generation matrix method. How this can be corrected?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, mathematical-modeling, mathematical-biology, epidemiology

I have a system of 6 ODE representing infected subpopulations of a model of epidemic
$$
\begin{cases}
\dfrac{de}{dt} =\dfrac{dy_2}{dt} = \phi y_1(y_4+y_5)-p_2 y_2\\
\dfrac{dq^*}{dt} =\dfrac{dy_3}{dt}  = \mu y_2 -P_3 y_3\\
\dfrac{ di_s}{dt} =\dfrac{dy_4}{dt} = \psi y_2 +\alpha y_3 -p_4 y_4\\
\dfrac{di_a}{dt} =\dfrac{dy_5}{dt} = \rho y_2+\sigma y_3 -p_5 y_5 \\
\dfrac{dh}{dt} =\dfrac{dy_6}{dt} =  \kappa y_4+l y_5+\nu y_7-p_6 y_6\\
\dfrac{dh_m}{dt} =\dfrac{dy_7}{dt}  = m y_5+h y_4-p_7 y_7 
\end{cases}
$$
**Here $y_2,\dots ,y_7$ are the number of people in different compartments.

Other epidemic parameters along with $y_1$ on the RHS are assumed to be non-negative.**

**I'm trying to find the basic reproduction number $R_0  $ using a next-generation matrix approach.**
The Jacobian matrix ($J$) for the infected sub-population is:
$$
J (y_2, y_3, \ldots, y_7)=
\begin{bmatrix}
 -p_2  & 0      & \phi y_1 & \phi y_1 & 0    & 0 \\
 \mu   & -P_3   & 0        & 0        & 0    & 0 \\
 \psi  & \alpha & -p_4     & 0        & 0    & 0 \\
 \rho  & \sigma & 0        & -p_5     & 0    & 0 \\
 0     & 0      & \kappa   & l        &-p_6  & \nu \\
 0     & 0      & h        & m        & 0    & -p_7 \\
\end{bmatrix}
 = T + Q ,
$$ where
$$
T=
\begin{bmatrix}
 0 & 0 & \phi y_1     &\phi y_1 & 0   & 0\\
 0 & 0 & 0    & 0 & 0 & 0\\
 0 & 0 & 0     & 0    & 0 & 0\\
 0 & 0 & 0    & 0     & 0 & 0\\
 0 & 0 & 0     & 0    & 0 & 0\\
 0 & 0 & 0     & 0    & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
$$ and
$$
Q=
\begin{bmatrix}
 -p_2 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 \mu & -P_3 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 \psi & \alpha & -p_4 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 \rho & \sigma & 0 & -p_5 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & \kappa & l & -p_6 & \nu \\
 0 & 0 & h & m & 0 & -p_7 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
For a large population, $R_0$= the dominant eigenvalue of the $NGM=TQ^{-1}$ which can be determined conveniently using computer programming like Matlab.
The inverse matrix of $Q$ is obtained by Gauss Jordan Method:\
$$
\begin{split}
[Q|I] &=
 \left(\begin{array}{cccccc|cccccc}
  -p_2  & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
  \mu  & -p_3  & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
  \psi  & \alpha  & -p_4  & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
  \rho  & \sigma  & 0 & -p_5  & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
  0 & 0 & \kappa  & l & -p_6  & \nu  & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
  0 & 0 & h & m & 0 & -p_7  & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1
 \end{array}\right)\\
\\
&=
\begin{array}{l}
 \left[\begin{array}{cccccc|cccccc}
  1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -\frac{1}{p_2 } & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
  0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -\frac{\mu }{p_2 \,p_3 } & -\frac{1}{p_3 } & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
  0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -\frac{\sigma_4 }{p_2 \,p_3 \,p_4 } & -\frac{\alpha }{p_3 \,p_4 } & -\frac{1}{p_4 } & 0 & 0 & 0\\
  0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & -\frac{\sigma_3 }{p_2 \,p_3 \,p_5 } & -\frac{\sigma }{p_3 \,p_5 } & 0 & -\frac{1}{p_5 } & 0 & 0\\
  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & -\frac{\sigma_4 \,\sigma_2 }{p_2 \,p_3 \,p_4 \,p_6 \,p_7 }-\frac{\sigma_1 \,\sigma_3 }{p_2 \,p_3 \,p_5 \,p_6 \,p_7 } & -\frac{\alpha \,\sigma_2 }{p_3 \,p_4 \,p_6 \,p_7 }-\frac{\sigma \,\sigma_1 }{p_3 \,p_5 \,p_6 \,p_7 } & -\frac{\sigma_2 }{p_4 \,p_6 \,p_7 } & -\frac{\sigma_1 }{p_5 \,p_6 \,p_7 } & -\frac{1}{p_6 } & -\frac{\nu }{p_6 \,p_7 }\\
  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & -\frac{h\,\sigma_4 }{p_2 \,p_3 \,p_4 \,p_7 }-\frac{m\,\sigma_3 }{p_2 \,p_3 \,p_5 \,p_7 } & -\frac{\alpha \,h\,p_5 +m\,p_4 \,\sigma }{p_3 \,p_4 \,p_5 \,p_7 } & -\frac{h}{p_4 \,p_7 } & -\frac{m}{p_5 \,p_7 } & 0 & -\frac{1}{p_7 }
 \end{array}\right]
\end{array}\\
\\
&=[I|Q^{-1}]
\end{split}
$$
where

- $\sigma_1 =m\nu +lp_7$
- $\sigma_2 =h\nu +\kappa p_7$,
- $\sigma_3 =\mu \sigma + p_3 \rho$,
- $\sigma_4 =\alpha \mu +p_3 \psi$

Therefore,
$$ 
Q^{-1} = 
  \left(\begin{array}{cccccc}
   -\frac{1}{p_2 } & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
   -\frac{\mu }{p_2 \,p_3 } & -\frac{1}{p_3 } & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
   -\frac{\sigma_4 }{p_2 \,p_3 \,p_4 } & -\frac{\alpha }{p_3 \,p_4 } & -\frac{1}{p_4 } & 0 & 0 & 0\\
   -\frac{\sigma_3 }{p_2 \,p_3 \,p_5 } & -\frac{\sigma }{p_3 \,p_5 } & 0 & -\frac{1}{p_5 } & 0 & 0\\
   -\frac{\sigma_4 \,\sigma_2 }{p_2 \,p_3 \,p_4 \,p_6 \,p_7 }-\frac{\sigma_1 \,\sigma_3 }{p_2 \,p_3 \,p_5 \,p_6 \,p_7 } & -\frac{\alpha \,\sigma_2 }{p_3 \,p_4 \,p_6 \,p_7 }-\frac{\sigma \,\sigma_1 }{p_3 \,p_5 \,p_6 \,p_7 } & -\frac{\sigma_2 }{p_4 \,p_6 \,p_7 } & -\frac{\sigma_1 }{p_5 \,p_6 \,p_7 } & -\frac{1}{p_6 } & -\frac{\nu }{p_6 \,p_7 }\\
   -\frac{h\,\sigma_4 }{p_2 \,p_3 \,p_4 \,p_7 }-\frac{m\,\sigma_3 }{p_2 \,p_3 \,p_5 \,p_7 } & -\frac{\alpha \,h\,p_5 +m\,p_4 \,\sigma }{p_3 \,p_4 \,p_5 \,p_7 } & -\frac{h}{p_4 \,p_7 } & -\frac{m}{p_5 \,p_7 } & 0 & -\frac{1}{p_7 }
  \end{array}\right)
$$
Now,
$$
T Q^{-1} = \left(\begin{array}{cccccc}
 -\frac{\phi \,y_1 \,{\left(\alpha \,\mu \,p_5 +p_3 \,p_5 \,\psi +\mu \,p_4 \,\sigma +p_3 \,p_4 \,\rho \right)}}{p_2 \,p_3 \,p_4 \,p_5 } & -\frac{\phi \,y_1 \,{\left(\alpha \,p_5 +p_4 \,\sigma \right)}}{p_3 \,p_4 \,p_5 } & -\frac{\phi \,y_1 }{p_4 } & -\frac{\phi \,y_1 }{p_5 } & 0 & 0\\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{array}\right)
$$
The eigenvalues of $TQ^{-1}$ are repesctively
$$
\left(\begin{array}{c}
 \lambda_1 \\
 \lambda_2 \\
 \lambda_3 \\
 \lambda_4 \\
 \lambda_5 \\
 \lambda_6 
\end{array}\right)=\left(\begin{array}{c}
0\\
0\\
0\\
0\\
0\\
-\frac{\phi \,y_1 \,{\left(\alpha \,\mu \,p_5 +p_3 \,p_5 \,\psi +\mu \,p_4 \,\sigma +p_3 \,p_4 \,\rho \right)}}{p_2 \,p_3 \,p_4 \,p_5 }
\end{array}\right)
$$
while the basic reproduction number is
$$ 
R_0=-\frac{\phi \,y_1 \,{\left(\alpha \,\mu \,p_5 +p_3 \,p_5 \,\psi +\mu \,p_4 \,\sigma +p_3 \,p_4 \,\rho \right)}}{p_2 \,p_3 \,p_4 \,p_5 }.
$$
I got the dominant eigenvalue of NGM as a negative term
$$
R_0=-\frac{\phi \,y_1 \,{\left(\alpha \,\mu \,p_5 +p_3 \,p_5 \,\psi +\mu \,p_4 \,\sigma +p_3 \,p_4 \,\rho \right)}}{p_2 \,p_3 \,p_4 \,p_5 }
$$
which is, I think not acceptable for an epidemic. How can I make this correct?

Comment: What is $y_{1}$?

Comment: $y_1$ no of susceptible  \begin{equation} 
   &\frac{ds}{dt}=\frac{dy_1}{dt}  = \beta  -\delta y_1-\phi y_1(y_4+y_5) \\
   &\frac{ de}{dt}=\frac{dy_2}{dt} = \phi y_1(y_4+y_5)-p_2 y_2\\
   &...,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,\\
   &,,,....................................................\\
   &... ...................................................\\
   &..........................\\
   &...................... \\
   &\frac{ dr_c}{dt}=\frac{dy_8}{dt} = n y_6+p y_5+q y_7 +r y_3-\delta y_8\\
   &\frac{dd^*}{dt}=\frac{dy_{9}}{dt} = \epsilon y_6+\eta y_7 \\
 \end{equation}